# Error connection to server: FATAL: role 'postgres' does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin

I've found that error when I connect postgres database with pgAdmin3. And I thought `postgres` username is lost but I've tried `psql -l` in terminal then I found postgres username still exist.

```
                         List of databases
   Name    | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges 
-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 postgres  | user  | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 template0 | user  | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | =c/user          +
           |       |          |         |       | user=CTc/user
 template1 | user  | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | =c/user          +
           |       |          |         |       | user=CTc/user
(3 rows)
```

Please let me know how to recover `postgres` issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`psql -l` lists databases , not users

`psql \du` does list users

here's a list of metacommands to refere:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS